# MySQL Boolean column changed from int to unsigned long

Tags: c#, mysql

On MySQL DB version `8.0.16` as read by C#, this query is interpreted as a datatype **long**

`SELECT (field = 1) as Result FROM table WHERE id = 1;`

In this case, the database `field` is of type int column.

We updated the DB to version `8.0.27` and the same query being read by the same connector is now being interpreted as a **ulong** which is causing some problems in old code that wants to cast it to a long.

While I will need to go into the old code and make it a little more robust, I am curious if anyone knows what happened between `8.0.16` and `8.0.27` to cause this difference in datatype?

Comment: **"the same query being read by the same connector"** - it would be helpful if you can specify the connector version or any orm involved.. also, see [this "bug"](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64084)

Comment: @BagusTesa I didn't need to clog the query with extraneous detail.  The bug you referenced is interesting but it is from 2013.  Version 8.0.16 was released in 2019.  Not saying it isn't related or couldn't have gone 6+ years before getting fixed.  Our DBAs confirmed that 8.0.16 returns a signed value while 8.0.27 returns an unsigned value.  They aren't sure why either, so they've escalated to Oracle to find out.  I was just hoping someone here would know before Oracle got around to it.

Comment: the important point of that bug report are: 1) it wasnt fixed, the documentations are rewritten instead; 2) it might be a relevant **regression**; 3) it said that "if the server says its a long then nothing you can do." which is why stating the version of the connector might be relevant. you cant just assume people able to replicate your issue with incomplete information.

Comment: also, if its pretty urgent, throw a bounty. hopefully experts will notice.

Comment: It's not urgent.  I've already fixed the legacy codebase to be more resilient to oracle's whims with its datatype.  I'll update this post with whatever answer we get back from Oracle support next week when they bother answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in MySQL Server 8.0.27 that was [fixed in version 8.0.28](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-28.html):

> A fix in MySQL 8.0.27 for a previous issue changed the resolved type of a boolean expression from signed `INT` to unsigned `BIGINT` in order to simplify type handling, but what appeared then as a harmless metadata change turned out to cause problems for some of the MySQL Connectors.
>
> We now revert the metadata change and provide a different fix for the original problem, by adjusting the max_length for the negation of an integer to at least two characters. (Bug #33516898)

You can test the behaviour in different versions of MySQL by using Docker. First, run the desired MySQL version:

```
docker run -d --rm --name mysqltest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -p 3306:3306 mysql:8.0.27
```

Then run the client and examine the column types:

```
docker exec -it mysqltest mysql -uroot -ppass --column-type-info -e "select (1 = 1);"
```

You can see that it was `UNSIGNED` in 8.0.27 but not 8.0.26 or 8.0.28:

```
Field   1:  `(1 = 1)`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     1
Max_length: 1
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NOT_NULL UNSIGNED BINARY NUM


+---------+
| (1 = 1) |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Since a boolean can only be 0 or 1, I guess they decided it would make more sense for it to return an unsigned value rather than signed.

You can specify the datatype explicitly with `CAST()`.

```
SELECT CAST((field = 1) AS SIGNED) As Result ...
```

Comment: Our DBAs confirmed that 8.0.16 returns a signed value while 8.0.27 returns an unsigned value.  Somewhere in there it was changed but not called out in any release notes we can find.  There's many ways around it, this was more to find the when/where.  Thank you though.  :)